# Scraping data from 'See all answers' button

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape reviews from this website : https://www.productreview.com.au/listings/aami-car-insurance?page=1#reviews . Each review container has 5 ratings (value for money, customer service etc.). when we initially load the page most of the info is hidden under the 'See all Answers' button. Therefore i can only scrape two of the ratings that show up at the top.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.productreview.com.au/listings/aami-car-insurance?page=1#reviews'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = bsoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

reviews = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class' , 'mb-0__MF overflow-hidden_Yg5 card_UzP card-full_soR card-full-md_tUp'})

ratings = reviews[0].find_all('div' , attrs = {'class' , 'flex-column__BR d-flex_RNf col-12_hGx col-md-6_qwV'})
ratings
```

I checked the network monitor and when the button is pressed a GET request is generated to fetch the data.

How do I scrape the data hidden under the button?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You emulate the same GET request that happens when you click the button...

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The same as you do `req = requests.get(url)` - just use the URL the button requests data from...

Answer (score 0):

Their API is exposed;

https://api.productreview.com.au/api/au/listings/aami-car-insurance/reviews?page=1&withAggregations=false&limit=25

Just loop through this and increment page, each loop page = page + 1 and so on; parse the JSON grab the items; simple :)